# How to exclude a dependecy from being installed via Maven using intelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have currently created a Maven project and located a duplicate dependency which is affecting my code from executing as intended.

I have both dependencies:
json-schema-validator
javax.mail

After further investigations it seems the json-schema-validator dependency also downloads a javax mail jar file, is there a way to exclude json-schema-validator from also downloading javax.mail related dependencies?

So far I have setup the following which does not seem to work:
[image]

[image]

As you can see from the image I have attempted to exclude the dependency, with no luck by using an exclusion within my pom.xml file.

Please note also the following exclusion does not seem to work:

```
  <exclusion>
           <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
           <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some misunderstands here:

- You do not need to exclude "duplicate" dependencies. Maven does not add them twice to the classpath. You need to care for version numbers, though. If different versions of the same artifact appear in your dependency tree, Maven chooses one of them. If you are not happy with the choice, you can overwrite it with `<dependencyManagement>`.
- if you write an exclusion (which you probably do not need here), you need to fill in the correct groupId and artifactId. If you try to exclude artifacs with the artifactId `javax.mail`, it is no wonder that `mailapi` is still there.

Comment: In my case both dependencies are listed as 1.4.3 as I have also directly added the following:        ` <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>` but im still facing the issue?

Comment: Your dependency is strange because you use `mail` as artifactId, while above you have `mailapi`. What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

It causes due to version conflict because same API used as dependent in another added dependency in POM file.

One of the solution is to first check hoe many times same API used with different version

> mvn dependency:tree

Above command will display all dependencies used in your project. Now exclude same dependency which is used as dependent.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

After applying changes update maven pom

```
mvn clean compile
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding the following exclusion resolved my issue:

```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
           <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
           <version>2.2.6</version>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                   <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
```

Comment: This might be the case, but exclusions are the wrong approach for these issues. Either declare the dependency `mailapi` yourself with the correct version or use `<dependencyManagement>`.